# HP ProCurve 3500 - monitor bandwith usage

Tags: bandwidth, switch

I would like to check the bandwith usage of a port. But I can't seem to find a show command that will let me do so. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the web interface you can check Port Status and hover over each port to get high use.  Not sure if you want more history.  Port counters will give total traffic. We use [Paessler PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg) to monitor actual traffic over time using SNMP.  Easy setup and free trial